# Why is Happy Buddha playing the "Titanic" theme in "How to Be Chinese"?

Tags: short-stories, allusions, celeste-ng

This is some description of the restaurant Happy Buddha from the short story ["How to Be Chinese"](https://gulfcoastmag.org/journal/26.1/how-to-be-chinese/). Bolding is mine.

> Look around to see what it’s like in a *real* Chinese restaurant. The tablecloths are pink and the napkins maroon. The teacups don’t have handles. Honeycomb balls of red paper and gold plastic bats dangle from joins in the ceiling tile. Worry that your people have bad taste. A woman croons in Chinese over the speaker system. Sit in a corner booth and imagine you’re in China. In a minute you recognize **the tune being piped in: it’s the theme from *Titanic***.

Many of the other little cultural references serve clear purposes, often marking something as either American or Chinese. I don't understand this one, however. *Titanic* is certainly not a Chinese film and yet it's playing in a place described as "authentic" and "a *real* Chinese restaurant". What is the purpose of this reference? Why this song?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Although not a Chinese production, *Titanic* became a Chinese cultural phenomenon.**

Briefly, the 1998 release of *Titanic* in China was the highest-grossing film in Chinese history, and was such a hit that even the then Chinese president publicly  took the whole politburo to see it.

For a lot more detail about this, you can read [Kaylin Dillon, "Hollywood in China:
The Chinese Reception of Titanic as a Case Study", MA thesis, University of Kansas (2015)](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/19029/Dillon_ku_0099M_13858_DATA_1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). Some relevant excerpts:

> *Titanic*’s overwhelming adoration in China places it as an important part of popular
> culture. Regardless of the acclaim or criticism of critics, the wave of craze surrounding *Titanic* is
> big enough that it should be looked at as a cultural phenomenon to be explored.

> *Titanic*’s impact on the Chinese box office in 1998 was historically unparalleled and *Titanic* was
> the highest grossing film in China for the next eleven years. The feature film made $24.4
> million in its first month in China, a phenomenon Chinese media called the Titanic “miracle”
> (*qiji*). *Titanic* was superseded once in 2009 by *Transformers* only to steal back its no. 1 spot
> with the 2012 re-release of *Titanic 3D*.

> *Titanic*
> enthusiasm spread quickly through China, even to outlying and distant areas. In “Titanic in
> China”, Jonathan Noble notes: “When visiting Lijiang in June 1997, one of my students asked
> the Naxi tour guide to sing a Naxi folk song. She agreed to sing, but selected ‘My Heart Will Go
> On.’ The following year, those selling bamboo flutes from Guizhou to Xinjiang had all apparently
> adopted the song as their advertising jingle”. In Zhang Yimou’s film, *The Road Home* (1999),
> two *Titanic* posters bedeck a wall in the home of a village teacher. One state-owned company
> bought tickets for all of its employees to see *Titanic* after reports emerged that then-party
> chairman Jiang Zemin was touting character Jack’s role as a working-class hero. All of these
> examples speak to how quickly and deeply *Titanic* penetrated various levels of Chinese culture.
> *Titanic*’s absorption into Chinese culture is evident, but China overwhelmingly surpasses the
> rest of the world in its adulation of the re-release of *Titanic 3D*. While the interest of American
> audiences waned quickly, the fanaticism of Chinese moviegoers has yet to subside. Chinese
> theaters demolished the box office sales of all other countries showing *Titanic 3D*. This is due,
> in part, to China’s large population and increase in theaters, but China also broke its own record
> for biggest opening at the box office with the $67 million grossed just from the debut of *Titanic
> 3D*.

Other (shorter) reading about this topic:

- [Blockbuster film has titanic impact on China’s culture](https://www.deseret.com/1998/4/28/19377082/blockbuster-film-has-titanic-impact-on-china-s-culture) - Deseret News (1998)
- [Why China Loves 'Titanic' So Much: A Theory](https://www.wsj.com/articles/BL-CJB-15687) - Wall Street Journal (2012)
- [Why do so many Chinese people like the film Titanic?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-so-many-Chinese-people-like-the-film-Titanic) - Quora
- [What China's Talking About Today: China Loves Titanic 3D](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2012/04/what-chinas-talking-about-today-china-loves-titanic-3d/255681/) - The Atlantic (2012)

I read Celeste Ng's short story and couldn't figure out exactly when it's set, but in any case it apparently makes sense for the *Titanic* theme to appear as part of "real Chinese culture": it's become, in some ways, even more of a cultural phenomenon in China than in the US.